# Relative Condition Number for $\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}$

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization, numerical-calculus

For a numerics problem, I have to find whether the function in the header is well-conditioned for large x with relative conditioning. In my understanding, I have to find the limit for x->inf of $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}}*\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}$. However, I cannot really calculate this limit on paper.

Is my approach right?
How can I calculate the limit?

Also, for a follow up problem, I have to find a numerically stable realization of the function - how would I do that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you know the binomial theorem and can you apply it here? Do you know the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$?

Comment: yes I know these, and for the normal term i can apply the binomial theorem. however, I don't see how I can apply it with the derivative form - or would you suggest first applying the theorem, then getting the derivative?

Comment: Please add more steps of what you tried, I can really not see where in this straightforward calculation there could be a difficulty. In floating point there is some point where the difference evaluates to zero, as $x+1$ is rounded to the same number as $x$. But that is not visible with the condition number.

Comment: The task description says to find whether the evaluation of said function is well conditioned for large x. Also it said to find that using relative conditioning. My idea therefore was to use the expression I've written down with the derivative. However, I just cannot get a solution for that limit. Might be I am not seeing something everybody else already has seen

Comment: So your problem is to simplify $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}}\left(\frac1{2\sqrt{x+1}}-\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}\right)$? The difference cancels, and it remains a rather simple fraction with the limit $-\frac12$.

Comment: It was requested to add the next steps. From above transforming to common denominator $=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}}·\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x+1}}{2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+1}}$, then cancel $=-\frac{x}{2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+1}}=-\frac12\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}$, from where the limit for $x\to+\infty$ is obvious.

Comment: Has the problem been resolved? Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f : (0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by $$f(x) = (1+x)^{\frac{1}{2}} - x^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$ Then $f$ is differentiable and $$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2} (1+x)^{-\frac{1}{2}} - \frac{1}{2} x^{-\frac{1}{2}}.$$
It follows that
$$ \frac{x f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{1}{2} x\frac{(1+x)^{-\frac{1}{2}} - x^{-\frac{1}{2}} }{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{2}} - x^{\frac{1}{2}}} = \frac{1}{2} x \frac{t^{-1} - s^{-1}}{t-s}, $$
where we have introduced $$t = (1 + x)^\frac{1}{2}, \quad s = x^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$ It follows that
$$ \frac{x f'(x)}{f(x)} = -\frac{1}{2}x \frac{1}{ts} = - \frac{1}{2} \frac{x^\frac{1}{2}}{(1+x)^\frac{1}{2}} = -\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{x}{1+x}}. $$
We conclude that $f$ is exceedingly well-conditioned in the relative sense and if $\kappa_f(x)$ denotes the relative condition number of the function $f$ at the point $x$, then $$\underset{x \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} \kappa_f(x) = \frac{1}{2}.$$ The difficulty associated with evaluating $f$ is an artifact of the cancellation that will almost certainly occur for large values of $x$. This problem can be addressed using, say, Taylor expansions. For example, since $$(1 + x) = x(1 + x^{-1})$$ we have
$$(1+x)^\frac{1}{2} \approx x^{\frac{1}{2}} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2} x^{-1} \right).$$ It follows that
$$f(x) \approx \frac{1}{2} x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$ is a good approximation for all sufficiently large $x$. It would be entirely proper to investigate when more terms are needed and when $x$ is sufficiently large, but perhaps these are questions for another day.